# Ubuntu Memory disappears after long up-time

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, ram, memory-usage

I've been having this problem for a few versions of Ubuntu now. Had 18.04 and upgraded to 20.04 on my Asus X552cl laptop.

The laptop is running 24/7 and only needs a restart because of this issue where when it starts up the system registers the full memory installed (12GB showing as 11.5GB in Ubuntu) but sometimes things will lag and then it only shows around 4GB installed. OS is of course 64-bit and it's not like it happens at specific times or for specific reasons that I can easily recreate it.

Like I said I've been using it a while now and it's more annoying than a real problem, but I'd like to try and find out what is the cause.

Any more details required please let me know and I'll post them.

My first thought was VLC causing the issue because the app will play during the night and the next morning if I close it the background process stays active and sometimes the issue would occur then. Moved over to totem which does not have the background process issue but memory will still sometimes vanish.

Then I thought it might be sleep mode as our power gets shut down due to load shedding, however, it's also not consistent as only a few times I've noticed missing memory when returning from sleep mode.

Comment: It'll depend what programs you're using...  I have such issues (and only have 8GB to start with) but for me I worked out it's `firefox` & `chromium`.  Those programs are fine before I add extensions; it's the extensions themselves that don't handle memory well... but I want to keep using those extensions, so I do... It just means I kill `firefox` and/or `chromium` when needed & issue is cleared (for a day or so anyway)...  Did you work out what program caused it?

Comment: "_then it only shows around 4GB **installed**_" Can you elaborate more on this? What is the `lsmem` output during this time?

Comment: `top -b 1 -o %MEM | head -n 15`  can maybe give you a hint.

Comment: Thanks all for the replies. I will try ` top -b 1 -o %MEM | head -n 15 ` next time it happens. It might be like guiverc said as I have `firefox` open 24/7 and it has a adblock extension. Maybe I should try a different adblock?
However personal issues are keeping me from replying sooner and testing. The memory problem hasn't happened again yet but I will try to see if the comments help, but won't reply immediatly. I will try toreply as I'm able.